# How to make Redis repositories transactional

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

Spring Data Redis [support repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis.repositories) as alternative to [redis templates](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template). But everything I found about [`@Transactional` support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#tx.spring) is about templates, not repositories.

*Is there any way to make redis repositories transactional?*

I added `@EnableTransactionManagement` and marked service method with transactional, but get the following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' available

Answer (score -1):

Spring Data Redis doesn't support transactions for Repository only for templates.